# Add new ranking columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a two diff frames

df1.csv

```
Reg1 Reg2
aaa  eee
bbb  fff
ccc  ggg
ddd  hhh
```

df2.csv

```
Reg,Rank
aaa,1 
bbb,3
ccc,4
ddd,5
eee,7
fff,9
ggg,10
hhh,11
```

newfram.csv

```
Reg1,Rank1,Reg2,Rank2
aaa,1,eee,7
bbb,3,fff,9
ccc,4,ggg,10
ddd,5,hhh,11
```

How do I achieve the newdata dataframe?

Comment: Can you please fix your formatting? [See formatting guide here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `dictionary` `d['Rank']`:

```
d = df2.set_index('Reg').to_dict()
print d['Rank']
{'aaa': 1, 'bbb': 3, 'ggg': 10, 'eee': 7, 'fff': 9, 'hhh': 11, 'ccc': 4, 'ddd': 5}


df = pd.concat([df1.Reg1, df1.Reg1.map(d['Rank']), df1.Reg2, df1.Reg2.map(d['Rank'])], 
                axis=1,
                keys=['Reg1','Rank1','Reg2','Rank2'])
print df
  Reg1  Rank1 Reg2  Rank2
0  aaa      1  eee      7
1  bbb      3  fff      9
2  ccc      4  ggg     10
3  ddd      5  hhh     11
```

For creating `DataFrames` from `csv` use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html). [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-read-csv-table).

Comment: Thanks a lot jezrael